# Ethereum facilitation for zk-SNARKs

Tags: privacy, zksnark, metropolis

There has been a lot of talk about leveraging zk-SNARKs to bring privacy features to the Ethereum Blockchain. My question is, how is Ethereum facilitating the verification of zk-SNARKs at the moment, and, moreover, what further steps are planned in this direction?

I am aware that Byzantinum, the first Metropolis hard fork, includes some changes (see EIP 198, EIP 212 (197) and EIP 213 (196) and compare with [ELI5: Byzantium Changes](https://www.reddit.com/r/ethereum/comments/702t95/eli5_byzantium_changes/)) in the form of pre-compiled contracts that allow for operations used in zk-SNARK verification, such as, e.g., elliptic curve addition and pairing. I am furthermore aware of ZoKrates, a stand-alone program that is able to compile a program (from what seems to be a limited set of programs) into yet another program which can generate a non-interactive zero-knowledge proof and a Smart Contract that does the on-chain verification. Unfortunately, I wasn't able to find any documentation on it.

I am wondering whether there is anything besides these EIPs and whether the support for zk-SNARK verification is going to stay at that level? Personally, I suspect that because Ethereum Smart Contracts can have arbitrary computations, the quadratic arithmetic programs (QAP) used to conduct zk-SNARKs, in general, differ vastly depending on the application such that a more high-level support is rendered infeasible.

Comment: I'd also be very curious about the current state of zk-SNARKS in Ethereum. I know that in permissioned versions Quorum has integrated zk-SNARKS in their ZSL PoC: https://github.com/jpmorganchase/quorum/wiki/ZSL

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, ZoKrates + Byzantium precompiles is the most generic solution currently available. Recently they also added sha256 support in ZoKrates, which extremely improves the applicability.

For tutorial and documentation for ZoKrates see https://zokrates.github.io/introduction.html

For more advanced examples see [ZKDai](https://medium.com/@atvanguard/zkdai-private-dai-transactions-on-ethereum-using-zk-snarks-9e3ef4676e22), which basically reassembles with ZoKrates the ZCash features.

Beside that, there are other solutions targeting special cases like [Aztec](https://github.com/AztecProtocol/AZTEC) or [ZK range proofs](https://www.ingwb.com/media/2122048/zero-knowledge-range-proof-whitepaper.pdf) made by ING.

Open challenges with ZK-SNARKS are still:

- trusted setup (toxic waste)
- onchain proof verification costs (~1,5M gas / verification)
- offchain proof creation (RAM consumption can easily go to couple of GB / proof)

Answer (score 1):

Here are the latest modern updates on this problem:

- Istanbul https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-1679 makes everything related to zkSNARKS cheaper
- EY implemented batch proofs https://github.com/EYBlockchain/nightfall where multiple ZKPs can be verified on-chain in with `cost(N) << N * cost(1)`.
- EY drafted a standard https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-1922 to recognize and interact with ZKP verifier contracts on-chain